# How to pass the debug argument from pm2 to a node process that uses a Coffeescript interpreter?

Tags: coffeescript, pm2

The following command is not behaving as expected. The debug argument is not reaching the Node process:

```
pm2 startOrRestart server.json --node-args="--debug=7001"
```

server.json file:

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name"             : "web",
      "cwd"              : "/home/app/",
      "instances"        : 1,
      "cron_restart"     : "*/30 * * * *",
      "script"           : "web/server.coffee",
      "exec_interpreter" : "coffee",
      "error_file"       : "logs/web-err.log",
      "out_file"         : "logs/web-out.log"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the node process that is launched by pm2 does not have the debug argument.

```
22:10   0:05 node /home/app/web/server.coffee
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that I am using the Coffeescript interpreter. For example, I can make things work as expected if I run the Coffee command directly (bypassing pm2), which starts up the node process in debug mode as expected:

```
coffee --nodejs --debug=5000 /home/app/web/server.coffee
```

How can I properly pass the debug argument from pm2 to coffee to node, so that it makes it all the way to the node process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding '--nodejs' also to --node-args option value, like

```
pm2 startOrRestart server.json --node-args="--nodejs --debug=7001"
```

If the interpreter is specified as 'coffee' then the coffee binary (or coffee-script npm package) will be used internally. So we have to give --node-args option value accordingly.